# What does it mean when having only a variable name in if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I usually understand if statements haha, but what does it mean when theres just a variable inside the if statement, is the code following always executed? In this case the variable legal is just an integer.

```
if (legal) 
    candidates[(*n)++] = i;
```

Comment: In C zero is false, and anything non-zero is true. So what the expression means is basically `if (legal != 0)`.

Comment: In C, any variable with value zero is taken to be "false", and any non-zero value is taken to be "true".

Comment: The reverse is also common: `if (!legal) ...`

Answer (score 2):

Non-zero values are treated as true, and zero values as false, so `if (value)` is equivalent to `if (value != 0)`.
In fact, pre-99 C does not even have a standard boolean type.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (legal)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (legal != 0)
```

Otherwise said, if I write:

```
if (legal)
{ 
  *instructions*
}
```

this means that `instructions` will only be executed if `legal` is a non-zero variable (`int`, or `char`, for example)